# Paginating One-to-Many Relationship Query with Unique Objects on the One Side and Filtered Eager Loading on the Many Side

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I paginate a one-to-many relationship query and retrieve unique objects on the one side (e.g., Author) while using the contains_eager option to eagerly load related objects on the many side (e.g., Book) based on a filter condition?

I tried query like this and I expected using limit and offset in the query might return duplicate objects on the one side. I need to ensure unique objects for pagination based on Author.

```
session.query(Author).join(Author.books).filter(Book.title.contains('Python')).options(contains_eager(Author.books)).limit(25).offset(0).all()
```